# Oracle CHAR column and trailing spaces with Hikari CP and JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

We have solved the problem selection from a column with trailing spaces CHAR type in Oracle db with Spring like

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * from PAYMENTS where CURRENCY_CODE=?",new SqlParameterValue(OracleTypes.FIXED_CHAR, currencyCode));
```

We would like to use datasource connection property fixedString=true as a general solution, but given properties has not been applied through configurations, but seen in debugging. Is there anything need to be applied that forgotten or is there any other approach we can try?

Properties, have been tried:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.additional.fixedString=true
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=fixedString=true
spring.datasource.connection-properties=fixedString=true;
```

Comment: You should probably use `spring.dataource.hikari.data-source-properties.fixedString = true`, assuming this is a valid connection property for Oracle. Alternative is to add it to the URL.

Comment: Tried different syntax versions of property, could not make it work. I have seen the property is set in debugging as config.getDataSourceProperties().put("fixedString", "true"), also tried boolean. Is there any general solution.

Comment: Figured out that FixedChar property is working with JDBC and UCP pool, but not with Hikari pool.